# Multithreading gzserver

Tags: gazebo-1.0

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to run gzserver over multiple cores does gzserver incorporate multithreading?

When running gzserver all the physics and plugin modelling is really only run over a single core, my computer has 4 cores and 8 threads and I was wondering if it were possible to run gzserver across more than one core inorder to get better performance. If gzclient is run a the same time, it spreads itself over the remaining cores, but for my application the gui is not really that important.

when running htop with gazebo running the gzserver runs over two threads, utilising one at 114% and the other at 98% but still only getting a real time factor of 0.08

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/571/multithreading-gzserver/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

At the moment multi-threading is not supported. There used to be a parallel_quickstep extension which allegedly worked in cturtle or diamondback but even there I only got it to compile but not run on multiple cores or even the GPU.

The only solution to this problem is probably to wait for a month until Bullet integration is finished which has a parallel solver and GPU support.

Btw. make sure you increase the update rate when decreasing the step size. 0.08 looks like you're running a 1e-4 step-size without increasing the update rate to 10k.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2012-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2013-01-03**:
how do you adjust that? I'm using Gazebo 1.0 as available in the ROS installation. I thought I read somewhere that the update was fixed to "as fast as possible", but had been made adjustable in Gazebo 1.2

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-09**:
I'd suggest updating to Gazebo 1.3.1

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2013-01-12**:
Hi Nate, please see my question regarding upgrade here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/761/how-do-i-update-from-the-fuerte-gazebo-release-to/